# script to automatically add a new row when filling the field of column 8

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a script to automatically add a blank line at the beginning whenever I finish filling the field in column 8 of a line?
Note: It is for this new line preserve the formula of the previous line.

This is the script that I am using.

It works by writing any part of the line (any column)

but I wanted him to be activated only when i write something in column 8.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    if (e) { 

      var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
        var r = e.source.getActiveRange(); 

        // If you want to be specific
        // do not work in first row
        // do not work in other sheets except "Outubro"
        if (r.getRow() != 1 && ss.getName() == "Outubro") {

            // E.g. status column is
            status = ss.getRange(r.getRow(), 8).getValue();

            // Status
          if (status == 'yes', 'null') {
                  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                  var folha = planilha.getActiveSheet();
                    if (folha.getName() === "Outubro")
                    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
                    sheet.insertRowBefore(4);

                    var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(3, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
                    rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(4, 1));
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that this isn't a code-writing service. Please edit your question to show what you've tried, what issue you're having, etc. Otherwise, it'll likely be closed shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help from the community.

The code is now working.

I'll leave the code here for anyone who need.

Once again thank you all for the help.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    if (e) { 

    var ss, activeRange, activeColumn;

        var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var folha = planilha.getActiveSheet();
        if (folha.getName() === "Outubro")

    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    activeRange = ss.getActiveRange();
    activeColumn = activeRange.getColumn();
    //Logger.log('activeColumn: ' + activeColumn); //VIEW LOGS

    if (activeColumn !== 8) {return;};//Quit if not column 8 {

        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
        sheet.insertRowBefore(4);

         var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(3, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
         rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(4, 1));
  }  
}
```